# Angular controllers: Accessing correct variable in controller using custom attribute with variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, controller, attributes

I created a custom `<select>` dropdown element using a directive, which has a `selecting` attribute that is used in the directive to pull the correct data from the controller to populate the list of options. I'd like to know if this is an appropriate use of AngularJS's different pieces. I'm new to Angular, but this is how it occurred to me to accomplish this task.

In the HTML partial for a page needing my version of `select`, this is all that needs to be written:

```
    <sliding-select selecting="areas"></sliding-select>
```

In the controller there is a corresponding variable on the main object called `areas` which contains within it an array called `options`, whose members should be the options of the area select.

And here is the part of the directive that takes that data and creates an option element for each member of the `areas` array :

```
    .directive('slidingSelect', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',

            compile: function(element, attrs) {
                var selecting = attrs.selecting;
                // ng-repeated options come from selecting attr
                var dropDownList = $('<div class="sliding-select-list"></div>');
                dropDownList.append('<div class="sliding-select-option" ng-repeat="item'+
                    ' in home.'+selecting+'.options">{{item.name}}</div>');
                element.append(dropDownList);

             }
         };
```

I'm just a bit worried that it seems hacky to create an element whose ng-repeat phrase uses the variable name by creating a string from it. Maybe there's a totally different approach to this problem that's preferred by the Angular community?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Angular's built-in `select` directive?

Comment: Yep, just building some functionality/appearances into it that are easier to handle when everything's a distinct element